# Execution failed for JetifyTransform in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I upgraded the react and react-native for my project. After upgrading the project I got the error from `react-native-reanimated`. I went through the official website for `react-native-reanimated` still dont know why I got this error.

```
Failed to transform react-native-reanimated-65-hermes.aar (project :react-native-reanimated) to match attributes {artifactType=android-manifest}.
```

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.65.0"
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I got the same error, I simply follow the documentation 
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation